# Get supervised child id from the children process

Tags: elixir

```
children = [
  %{
    id: worker_1,
    start: {Stack, :start_link, [[:hello]]}
  },  
  %{
    id: worker_2,
    start: {Stack, :start_link, [[:hello]]}
  }
]
```

How can you know inside the children process which children id are you? (without sending it as a param)

Comment: How about use `self()` in children processes?

Comment: with self() I get the PID not the actual id (worker_1, worker_2, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NB** Generally speaking, if you find yourself looking up your `id`, you are doing something wrong. But this is still possible.

Use [`Supervisor.which_children/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1) from inside your `child` implementation:

```rb
defmodule Stack do
  use GenServer

  def lookup_self_id(sup) do
    self_pid = self()

    sup
    |> Supervisor.which_children()
    |> Enum.find(fn
         {id, ^self_pid, _, _} -> id # pinned self → it’s me!
         _ -> nil                    # skip everything else
       end)
  end
end
```

Assuming the child known the supervisor’s `pid` *or* the supervisor is *named*, you pass either `pid` or `name` to this function, iterate through it’s children and detect yourself by the `pid`.